# Using an image path passed in props React, without import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-functional-component

I have lots of images in my project that I want to use dynamically depending on the user's needs. So I'm having a local db.js file having all the images paths and I'm passing them as props to be displayed but it's not working. I also can't import 50+ images in the component, there has to be an easier way.

```
function Component(props){
    return(
        <div>
            <img src={props.img} alt="..."/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The above code doesn't work as the relative path of the image is passed from the props, what can I do to dynamically import the passed path from the prop and use it in the src?

I tried this code to import the passed prop, but it didn't work as well.

```
function Component(props){

    async function importImage(){
        const img = await import(props.img)
        return img.default
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <img src={importImage()} alt="..."/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
The db.js file is as follows:

    const db = 
{
    winterJakcets: [
        {
            name: "Canada Goose Jacket",
            gender: "men",
            img: "../src/media/winterJacket/CGwinterJ_11.webp",
            price: 1299,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit",
            imgArray: ["../media/winterJacket/CGwinterJ_12.webp","../media/winterJacket/CGwinterJ_12.webp", "../media/winterJacket/CGwinterJ_12.webp"]
        }
}
```

Comment: Added the db file snippet